# Ionic not return data from variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, chart.js, ionic4

im creating a chart using chart.js. and i have 3 function here `dataSurvey` i use it to return my data from database and `createBarChart` to generate the chart and then `handle` to handle onclick chart, im want to display some info when user click the chart.

my variable and loaded function

```
dataSurveys:any

ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.dataSurvey()
  }
```

my `dataSurvey` code

```
dataSurvey() {
      this.api.get('product/getsurvey/'+this.CekLogin.data.id)
        .subscribe((result:any) => {
            this.dataSurveys = result.data
            if (this.dataSurveys) {
                this.createBarChart()
            }
        })
}
```

my `createBarChart` code

```
createBarChart() {
    this.bars = new Chart(this.barChart.nativeElement, {
      type: 'pie',
      data: {
        labels: this.dataSurveys.prodName,
        datasets: [{
          data: this.dataSurveys.prodScore,
          backgroundColor: this.dataSurveys.prodColor,
          borderColor: 'rgb(38, 194, 129)',
          borderWidth: 1
        }]
      },
      options: {
        onClick: this.handle
      }
    });
}
```

and my `handle` code

```
handle(point, event) {
    let item = event[0]
    console.log(item)
    console.log(this.dataSurveys)
  }
```

i try this command `console.log(this.dataSurveys)` on `dataSurvey` and `createBarChart` function, it return the data, but when i run it from `handle` function it return me 'undefined'.

how i can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably `this` in the context of `handle` method is something else ... not your Ionic Page. You can `console.log(this)` and see what it actually is.

If you actually need to use the variables logic from your page you can use the JS method apply. It will basically substitute the context with the one you need.

```
options: {
        onClick: this.handle.apply(this)
      }
```

See more information here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_apply.asp

Comment: not really right. btw, with your clue i solved my problem, thanks..